# HAPI FHIR try to use patch

Tags: patch, hapi-fhir, hl7-fhir

I've this resource of type `Paramaters` as follow:

```
{
  "resourceType": "Parameters",
  "parameter": [
    {
      "name": "operation",
      "part": [
        {
          "name": "type",
          "valueCode": "add"
        },
        {
          "name": "path",
          "valueString": "Organization"
        },
        {
          "name": "name",
          "valueString": "active"
        },
        {
          "name": "value",
          "valueString": "true"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Because I want to add active value on my Organization.

So I write, in according with [HAPI FHIR documentation - 4.2.7 paragraph](https://hapifhir.io/hapi-fhir/docs/client/generic_client.html), this code to execute a patch:

```
fhirClientR4Configuration.clientFhihrR4().patch().withBody(body).withId("Organization/2381").execute();
```

But I have this error:

> ca.uhn.fhir.rest.server.exceptions.InvalidRequestException: HTTP 400 :
> Cannot deserialize instance of
> java.util.ArrayList<com.github.fge.jsonpatch.operation.JsonPatchOperation>
> out of FIELD_NAME token  at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]

I've noticed I must put in the same array all informations about patch (in the tag part), but I don't know I can resolve it.

Tha HAPI FHIR version is 4.2.0